# Typescript rest operator arguments keyof object

Tags: typescript

How do you define function arguments with the rest operator to be an array of keys defined in a given type? I also need the return object to be an object shaped by the given argument keys & their corresponding types from the `T` type.

```
  type MyType<T> = {
    ...,

    // This is my struggle function
    myCallableFunction(...keys: keyof T[]) => object
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer I was looking for ended up using [`Pick`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#picktype-keys):

```
type MyType<T> = {
    myFunctionCall<U extends keyof T>(...keys: U[]): Pick<T, U>;
};
```

The object that `myFunctionCall` returns will have the listed properties from `T` with their value types as defined on `T`. So if `T` has the properties `a` and `b` of type `number` and `c` and `d` of type `string`, then the return type of `theObject.myFunction("a", "c")` will be `Pick<T, "a" | "c">`, which is `{a: number; c: string;}` (in that example).

[Playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=6#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)