# How to use Typescript to define a generic function signature

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-generics

I have this dataset:

```js
const dataset = [
  { date: "2022-01-01", category: "red", value: 10 },
  { date: "2022-01-01", category: "blue", value: 20 },
  { date: "2022-01-01", category: "gold", value: 30 },
  { date: "2022-01-01", category: "green", value: 40 },
  { date: "2022-01-02", category: "red", value: 5 },
  { date: "2022-01-02", category: "blue", value: 15 },
  { date: "2022-01-02", category: "gold", value: 25 },
  { date: "2022-01-02", category: "green", value: 35 }
];
```

And I need to flat the dataset to get this:

```js
const flattenDataset = [
  { "date": "2022-01-01", "red": 10, "blue": 20, "gold": 30, "green": 40 },
  { "date": "2022-01-02", "red": 5, "blue": 15, "gold": 25, "green": 35 }
]
```

So group dataset by `date`s and for each `category` create a key with `value` as value.
I created this function:

```js
export function flatDataset(
  dataset: any,
  mainProperty: string,
  categoryProperty: string,
  valueProperty: string
) {
  if (dataset.length === 0 || !mainProperty) {
    return (dataset as unknown);
  }
  const columnToBeFlatValues = uniqBy(dataset, categoryProperty).map(
    (d) => d[categoryProperty]
  );
  const datasetGroupedByMainProperty = groupBy(dataset, mainProperty);
  const datasetGroupedByMainCategoryFlat = Object.entries(
    datasetGroupedByMainProperty
  ).map(([date, datasetForDate]) => {
    const categoriesObject = columnToBeFlatValues.reduce((acc, value) => {
      const datum = datasetForDate.find(
        (d) => d[mainProperty] === date && d[categoryProperty] === value
      );
      acc[value] = datum?.[valueProperty];
      return acc;
    }, {});
    return {
      [mainProperty]: date,
      ...categoriesObject
    };
  });
  return datasetGroupedByMainCategoryFlat;
}
```

It works but I would like to fix TypeScript.
For example the dataset type should not be `any` but an array of objects with keys with name `mainProperty`, `categoryProperty`, `valueProperty`.

For example, dataset could also be:

```js
const dataset = [
  { apple: ..., color: ..., something: ... },
  ...
];
const flattenDataset = flatDataset(dataset, 'apple', 'color', 'something')
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

There's a few way to make it

```
let obj = { apple: 's', sonic: 'a' , etc: 'd'}

function MyFunction<T, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, ...args:K[]): void { }

MyFunction(obj, 'apple', 'sonic', 'etc')
```

Using Generics with Rest Arguments. I used this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67689848/typescript-rest-operator-arguments-keyof-object) as example to create the rest args. I recommend you create an interfaces for maintein all sorted

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the right generic types you're looking for.
The main trick is using `{ [k in Enum]: string }`, which allows dynamically restricting a key of an object to be a part of a union of strings.

Please note you're using functions without their implementations, so it's hard to actually test it.

```
function flatDataset<Main extends string, Category extends string, Value extends string>(
    dataset: ({ [k in Main | Category]: string } & { [k in Value]: number })[],
    mainProperty: Main,
    categoryProperty: Category,
    valueProperty: Value,
): ({ [k in (typeof dataset)[number][Main]]: string }
    & { [k in (typeof dataset)[number][Category]]: number })[]
```